# Woocommerce - display price in two currencies at the same time?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, currency, price

For legal reasons I'll soon have to display all prices in local currency + EUR at the same time.

I have WPML with multicurrency enabled, and I can set an exchange rate there. Problem is - it only works with currency switcher widget, and doesn't allow me to display both currencies at the same time (one under other). So, the other price is already calculated somewhere, but I don't know how to retrieve it and display it by adding something to functions.php of child theme.

Alternatively, there is no need to use WMPL Multicurrency here. Exchange rate is fixed, so it would be sufficient to just somehow divide the original price with fixed exchange rate and display it with other currency symbol. I'm aware that original price is already HTML formatted and contains the original currency symbol. Hence - no arithmetic operations can be used unless it's converted to number and currency symbol is stripped.

I've tried using this solution: [Display prefixed price and additional unit price in Woocommerce simple products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63054379/display-prefixed-price-and-additional-unit-price-in-woocommerce-simple-products), but I end up with prices like this:

Original price: 99.00 $

Calculated price with fixed "exchange rate" entered in  `$unit_divider = 1.1;`: 90.00 **$** €

Note that here I managed to do the calculation and conversion, but I'm stuck with **$** symbol.

P.S. I only need to display the price on product pages and archives - it's not necessary to have both currencies in cart and checkout (but it would be great to have that too!).

Thanks for help!

Comment: I would suggest just copy templates in your theme and add manualy what u need. That will be hella confusing store. At the end user wont know in what currency is paying but w/e.