# How to show the lowest price of a variable in woocommerce product by specifying the price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I have a WordPress woo-commerce site I'm working on which has variable products of 1pack, 5pack, 10pack & 30pack. The price for 1pack if you choose the 30pack variant is the cheapest, and this is the price I wish to show to people who visit the site. I'm trying to have a place in the back end of the site where this price can be specified and displayed, as the calculation varies for each product.

I modified this code here [Display prefixed price and additional unit price in Woocommerce simple products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63054379/display-prefixed-price-and-additional-unit-price-in-woocommerce-simple-products).

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'unit_product_price_on_archives', 10, 2 );
function unit_product_price_on_archives( $price, $product ) {
if ( is_product() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) {
    $unit_divider = 6;
    $group_suffix = ' '. __('pack', 'woocommerce');
    $unit_suffix = ' '. __('(per pack)', 'woocommerce');

    if( $product->is_on_sale() )
    {
        $regular_price_unit = $product->get_regular_price() / $unit_divider;
        $regular_price_unit = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $regular_price_unit ) );

        $regular_price_group = $product->get_regular_price();
        $regular_price_group = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $regular_price_group ) );
      
        $group_price_sale = $product->get_sale_price();
        $group_price_sale = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $group_price_sale ) );

        $group_price_sale = wc_format_sale_price( $regular_price_group, $group_price_sale ) . $group_suffix;


        $unit_price_sale = $product->get_sale_price() / $unit_divider;
        $unit_price_sale = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $unit_price_sale ) );
        $unit_price_sale = wc_format_sale_price( $regular_price_unit, $unit_price_sale ) . $unit_suffix;
     
        $price = $group_price_sale . '<br>' . $unit_price_sale;
    }
    else
    {
        $group_price = $price;
        $group_price = $group_price . $group_suffix;
        $unit_price = $product->get_price() / $unit_divider;
        $unit_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $unit_price ) );
        $unit_price = $price = wc_price($unit_price) . $unit_suffix;
        $price = $group_price . '<br>' . $unit_price;
    }
}
return $price; 
}
```

But the code only divided the original simple product by 6.

Answer (score 0):

this should achieve the result you're looking for:

```
/** Variable Product Price Range: "From: $$$min_price" */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', ' 
bbloomer_variation_price_format_min', 9999, 2 );
function bbloomer_variation_price_format_min( $price, $product ) {
$prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );
$min_price = current( $prices['price'] );
$price = sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $min_price ) );
return $price;
}
```