# Woocommerce Display price in M2 and Regular price and checkout with regular price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, label

In Woocommerce I trying to find the way to show multiple prices.

Imagine I have an product and I sell it **100 € / m2** and the price of the full box is **170 € / box** that's mean I have **1,70m2 pre box**

I wanted to show 2 type of prices as final result. And final payment need to be per box.

thank you! I think is interesting, so if I don't get any help, I will try to find a solution and post here, just need to mindstorm with someone.

I have tryed many things like this:
[Display on shop pages the unit price and the wholesale price on product pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938280/display-on-shop-pages-the-unit-price-and-the-wholesale-price-on-product-pages/48939646#48939646)

Answer (score 0):

So I wanted to answer to my own question.

```
 /* A note on field visibility depending on product type */
    add_action('woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data', function() {
        woocommerce_wp_text_input([
            'id' => '_number_in_package',
            'label' => __('M2', 'txtdomain'),
            'wrapper_class' => 'show_if_simple'
        ]);
    });
    
    /* Saving your custom field */
    
    add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', function($post_id) {
        $product = wc_get_product($post_id);
        $num_package = isset($_POST['_number_in_package']) ? $_POST['_number_in_package'] : '';
        $product->update_meta_data('_number_in_package', sanitize_text_field($num_package));
        $product->save();
    });
    
    /* Outputting your custom field in frontend */
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', function() {
        global $post;
        $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);
        $num_package = $product->get_meta('_number_in_package');
        if (!empty($num_package)) {
            printf('<div class="custom-sku">%s %s</div>', __('', 'txtdomain' ), $num_package );
        }
    });
```